Confusion about line integral? two different ways derive two different result
Let $C$ be a counterclockwise path with circle which is centered at origin and radius is $2$ and $y\geq 1$.
Evaluate
$$\int_C \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}dx + \frac{x}{x^2 +y^2 + 1}dy$$

I tried two different ways.
The first method is since all points on $C$ must satisfies $x^2 + y^2 +1=5$, our vector field is
$$F = \left(\frac{y}{5}, \frac{x}{5}\right)$$
and this vector field is conservative with potential function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{5}$$
So, due to the Fundamental theorem of line integral, our integral must be
$$(-2)\times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{5}$$

And next way is using parameterization :
$$C(t) : (\cos t, \sin t)\quad (\theta \leq t\leq \pi-\theta)$$
where
$$\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}, \cos\theta = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
This leads our line integral to
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{5}\int_{\theta}^{\pi-\theta} \cos^2 t-\sin^2 tdt &= \frac{1}{5}\int_{\theta}^{\pi-\theta} \cos(2t)dt \\ &= -\frac{1}{5}\sin(2\theta) \\ 
&= -\frac{2}{5}\sin\theta \cos\theta \\ 
&= -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{10}\end{align}$$
which is different result.
So my question is which method is valid?
If both of them are valid, where did I make a mistake?

$C(t) : \color{red}2(\cos t, \sin t)\quad (\theta \leq t\leq \pi-\theta)$

@AnneBauval Thanks for correction, now both of them has same result, but I still have a question, the first one is also valid? Is there no problem to manipulate vector field like this?

It is fine.${}$
